# Grails 3.3.2: NPE in fields plugin - decapitalizedName?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, scaffolding

I upgraded my app from Grails `3.2.11` to `3.3.2` and went into this issue.

I have a class:

```
class Measure {
  String name
  Map<String,String> titles = [:]
  static hasMany = [ units:Unit ]
}
```

and the scaffolded `index.gsp` with:

```
<f:table collection="${measureList}" properties="[ 'name', 'units', 'titles' ]"/>
```

When I try to open the page, I get

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'decapitalizedName' on null object
>       at grails.plugin.formfields.FormFieldsTagLib.displayAssociation(FormFieldsTagLib.groovy:815)
>       at grails.plugin.formfields.FormFieldsTagLib.renderDefaultDisplay(FormFieldsTagLib.groovy:770)
>       at grails.plugin.formfields.FormFieldsTagLib.renderDisplayWidget(FormFieldsTagLib.groovy:441)
>       at grails.plugin.formfields.FormFieldsTagLib$_closure8.doCall(FormFieldsTagLib.groovy:357)

I tried to triangulate the problem, and found out that if I remove the `titles` property from `<f:table>` then it works fine. 
The show/edit views have no problems displaying the `titles` prop.

Any way to avoid the problem? Shall I file a JIRA?

Comment: If `titles` is an assocation, you need to say it is `hasMany = [titles: String]`

Comment: No, it's embedded

Comment: Do you have `static embedded = ['titles']` in your domain?

Comment: Hi @injecteer, were you able to find a fix/workaround for this issue? I'm having the same issue with a scaffolded controller

Comment: @drake the problem is in `f:table` / fields plugin. Build the table per hand

Comment: @injecteer I tried your example with Grails 3.3.6 with the default scaffold controller, I didn't get any NPE but the values aren't shown, this issue seems to be fixed, if you want to show the values in the list you can override the default at `views/templates/_fields/_table.gsp`, you can customize "https://github.com/grails-fields-plugin/grails-fields/blob/master/grails-app/views/templates/_fields/_table.gsp" file and replace `<f:display />`with `<g:fieldValue />` tag.